# How to execute non-timestamp-based aggregations in spark structured streaming?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

Consider the following *intended* sql:

```
select row_number() 
  over (partition by Origin order by OnTimeDepPct desc) OnTimeDepRank,* 
  from flights
```

This will *not* work in *structured streaming* - as shown in the following question [Spark - Non-time-based windows are not supported on streaming DataFrames/Datasets;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53294809/spark-non-time-based-windows-are-not-supported-on-streaming-dataframes-dataset/55777253#55777253) by my own answer to that question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55777253/1056563

The culprit is:

```
 partition by Origin
```

The requirement is to use a timestamp-typed field such as

```
 partition by flightTime
```

This requirement comes from a definitive source (core committer for *spark streaming*) - specifying that  *timestamp* based aggregations are supported. The syntax in that case is using `window`:

```
window("timestamp", "10 minutes")`
```

There is actually an additional complication:  ***Structured Streaming does not support correlated subqueries***.  Therefore the generally useful answers from the esteemed *Gordon Linoff* here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46856508/1056563  can not be applied

*What then* for my query above - which *must* be based on the *Origin* field?  What is the closest equivalent to that query? Or what would be a workaround or different approach to achieve same results?

Comment: I thought that windowed aggregations (`over` operator) are not supported at al (and that's what TD said in the answer you linked). So it's not about `partition by Origin` to be `partition by flightTime`, but whatever you want to achieve with the window aggregation you simply have to re-design the streaming query with some other algorithm. What are you really trying to do?

Comment: The `partition` was intended for showing the intent - the actual syntax is `window`: I updated the question .

Comment: @JacekLaskowski  I would *really* appreciate some insight on what ***other*** approaches might be possible here.  I am *really* trying to do what is exactly in the query here -and it is *REALLY difficult to understand how to translate this to structured streaming.