# Ranking without Rank()

Tags: sql, sql-server, rank

Here is the table:

```
StuId   Name    Class   Marks
-----------------------------
2003    aman    X-A     91
2005    ankita  X-A     89
2010    Aakash  X-A     87
2011    Cyril   X-A     87
2012    Bala    X-B     87
2013    Sara    X-C     89
2014    Katlyn  X-C     89
2015    Casy    X-C     87
2016    Katie   X-B     93
```

I need output table to be:

```
StuId   Name    Class   Marks Rank
-----------------------------------
2003    aman    X-A     91    1
2005    ankita  X-A     89    2
2010    Aakash  X-A     87    3
2011    Cyril   X-A     87    3
2016    Katie   X-B     93    1
2012    Bala    X-B     87    2
2013    Sara    X-C     89    1
2014    Katlyn  X-C     89    1
2015    Casy    X-C     87    3
```

For which I executed the following query:

```
SELECT *,
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Class ORDER BY Marks DESC) AS Rank
FROM StudentTable;
```

But how do I get the same result without using `Rank()`?

Comment: But why don't you want to use Rank()? Are you facing any performance issues?

Comment: No Issues using Rank(), I have been given this as a task.

Comment: Possible solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46856267/implement-rank-without-using-analytic-function.

Comment: Can you use other window functions?

Comment: I can use Count()

Comment: You can use ROW_NUMBER() instead

Comment: *I have been given this as a task.* but you are allowed to have someone else do it for you? Or was it perhaps intended for you to work it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In words, the rank of the student would be the number of students who have higher score than hir **plus one**. E.g. the students with 87 marks have 89 and 91 before them so they are ranked 3:

```
SELECT t.*, (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM StudentTable AS x
    WHERE x.Class = t.Class
    AND x.Marks > t.Marks
) + 1 AS Rank
FROM StudentTable AS t
ORDER BY t.Class, Rank
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/39997b/2)

Answer (score 3):

You could try with a correlated subquery that uses a count distinct for marks higher or equal in the same "Class".

```
SELECT *, 
(
 SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT s2.Marks) 
 FROM StudentTable s2 
 WHERE s2.Class = s.Class 
   AND s2.Marks >= s.Marks
) AS Rank
FROM StudentTable s
ORDER BY Class, Marks DESC;
```

A test *db<>fiddle can be found [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=924e720f20d5b36bc9ea3cfd075b74f8)*

But RANK will be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

I am creating temporary table with identity key in order to sort the rows. When an `INSERT` is performed against table with `IDENTITY` column, the `ORDER BY` clause is respected by the SQL engine.

Then, I am using recursive CTE to create a `RANK` column for each row. The idea is simple:

- if the `class` is changed, restart the ranking
- if the `class` is the same and `marks` the same - use same rank (increase counter of current rank)
- if the `class`is the same and the `marks` are not, increase the rank with `1` and reset the counter of rank

We are using such counter in order to get implement `RANK` behavior, for `DENSE_RANK` we do not need such counter.

So, the code is like this:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
    [StudID] INT
   ,[Name] VARCHAR(12)
   ,[Class] VARCHAR(12)
   ,[Marks] TINYINT
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([StudID], [Name], [Class], [Marks])
VALUES ('2003', 'aman', 'X-A', '91')
      ,('2005', 'ankita', 'X-A', '89')
      ,('2010', 'Aakash', 'X-A', '87')
      ,('2011', 'Cyril', 'X-A', '87')
      ,('2012', 'Bala', 'X-B', '87')
      ,('2013', 'Sara', 'X-C', '89')
      ,('2014', 'Katlyn', 'X-C', '89')
      ,('2015', 'Casy', 'X-C', '87')
      ,('2016', 'Katie', 'X-B', '93');

CREATE TABLE #DataSource
(
    [StudID] INT
   ,[Name] VARCHAR(12)
   ,[Class] VARCHAR(12)
   ,[Marks] TINYINT
   ,[RowID] INT IDENTITY(1,1)
)

INSERT INTO #DataSource ([StudID], [Name], [Class], [Marks])
SELECT [StudID], [Name], [Class], [Marks]
FROM @DataSource
ORDER BY [Class] ASC, [Marks] DESC;

WITH DataSource AS
(
    SELECT *
          ,1 AS [Rank]
          ,0 AS [RanksCount]
    FROM #DataSource
    WHERE [RowID] = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DS1.*
          ,CASE WHEN DS1.[Class] = DS2.[Class] 
                THEN CASE WHEN DS1.[Marks] = DS2.[Marks] THEN DS2.[Rank] ELSE DS2.[Rank] + DS2.[RanksCount] + 1 END
                ELSE 1
           END
          ,CASE WHEN DS1.[Class] = DS2.[Class] 
                THEN CASE WHEN DS1.[Marks] = DS2.[Marks] THEN DS2.[RanksCount] + 1 ELSE 0 END
                ELSE 0
           END
    FROM #DataSource DS1
    INNER JOIN DataSource DS2
        ON DS1.[RowID] = DS2.[RowID] + 1

)
SELECT *
FROM DataSource
ORDER BY [RowID];


DROP TABLE #DataSource;
```

[image]

Note, this is an idea. You can replace the `CASE WHEN` statements with `IIF` or you can write the CTE in different way (without using second table for storing the data).

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The following works with count only although you're better off using rank:

```
COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Class ORDER BY Marks ASC RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING  AND CURRENT ROW)
    - COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Class,Marks) + 1
```

Alternatively you could use a correlated sub query, this uses just a pure count but will be slower:

```
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM StudentTable AS CountMe WHERE StudentTable.Class = CountMe.Class AND StudentTable.Marks > CountMe.Marks) + 1 AS Rank
```