# Pervasive SQL - Add a Rank Column to a Sorted Recordset

Tags: sql, pervasive, pervasive-sql

In [Pervasive 13](https://docs.actian.com/psql/PSQLv13/#page/sqlref%2Fscalarfunc.htm%23), I'm looking for a way to add a [rank](https://learnsql.com/blog/how-to-rank-rows-in-sql/) column to a sorted record set.

For example, let's pretend that I have a `customer` table that has a field called `profit` (which is maintained to indicate the total profit from each customer). Instead of just sorting by profit, I also want to include each customer's rank based on profit, where the highest profit customer is ranked `1`, the second highest is ranked `2`, and so on.

```
select
     row_number() as "Rank"
    ,customer as "Customer"
from customers
order by profit desc
```

`row_number()`, above, is conceptual; it doesn't actually work in Pervasive 13, but I'm hoping there is something else that can achieve the same concept to produce a record set that looks like this:

```
Rank |Customer         |
-----+-----------------+
  1  |LUCRATIVE TECH   |
  2  |ROY INDUSTRIES   |
  3  |CRON INC.        |
  4  |FLEX PRODUCTS    |
  5  |CATCO CO.        |
```

Using only a SQL query, how can I produce a record set that contains a `rank` column like above in Pervasive 13?

Comment: I wonder how this can be done with just standard SQL (without engine-specific rank functions, which I'm so far unable to find in Pervasive 13). Current, I'm reading this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58517030/ranking-without-rank) for ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this seems to work for me using a much smaller / manufactured dataset.

```
create table customers (id identity, customer char(20), profit integer);

insert into customers values (0,'cust1',5);
insert into customers values (0,'cust2',4);
insert into customers values (0,'cust3',1);
insert into customers values (0,'cust4',3);
insert into customers values (0,'cust5',2);
insert into customers values (0,'cust6',2);

select 
(select 1 + count(*)
        from customers c2
        where c2.profit < c.profit
       ) as "rank"
    , c.*
from customers c
order by "rank"
```

Results:

```
       rank            id   customer                    profit
===========   ===========   ====================   ===========
          1             3   cust3                            1
          2             5   cust5                            2
          3             4   cust4                            3
          4             2   cust2                            4
          5             1   cust1                            5
```

Comment: Close, but I'm wanting: "The higher the profit the lower the rank." Perhaps ordering by `c.profit desc` will achieve that.

Comment: Now I understand why other SQL engines have created engine-specific functions for this task: this methodology becomes quite verbose on more complicated queries having multiple sub-queries and joins. Having a function like row_number(), reduces a lot of bloat (it can reduce the entire query's character count almost in half).