# Get top rows by "category" from a collection

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I am using Couchbase and N1QL.

Let's say I have a table of products. Products have a `categoryId` and a `price` among other attributes:

| id | name | categoryId | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | product 1 | cat1 | 5 |
| 2 | product 2 | cat2 | 100 |
| 3 | product 3 | cat1 | 25 |

I know how to get the 5 most expensive products for a single category. I would do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM products
WHERE categoryId = 'cat1'
ORDER BY price DESC
LIMIT 5
```

But how would I query for the top 5 most expensive products *per category*? I know I can do a `WHERE categoryId IN ['cat1', 'cat2']` but this would result in the top5 products among those categories, and not *per category*.

Any couchbase or N1QL experts that can help me out?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use WINDOW functions

```
SELECT p1.*, MISSING AS r
FROM (SELECT p.*, 
      RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY p.categoryId ORDER BY p.price DESC) AS r
      FROM products AS p
      WHERE p.categoryId IS NOT NULL) AS p1
WHERE p1.r < 6;
```

Non-Window functions (UNNEST should perform better)

```
CREATE INDEX ix1 ON products(categoryId, price DESC);

SELECT p2.*, MISSING AS r
FROM (SELECT p.*,
      (SELECT RAW 1+COUNT(1)
       FROM products AS p1
       WHERE p1.categoryId = p.categoryId AND p1.price > p.price)[0] AS r
      FROM products AS p
      WHERE p.categoryId IS NOT NULL) AS p2
WHERE p2.r < 6;

OR

SELECT u.*
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT RAW p.categoryId
      FROM products AS p
      WHERE p.categoryId IS NOT NULL) AS c
UNNEST (SELECT p1.*
    FROM products AS p1
    WHERE p1.categoryId = c
    ORDER BY p1.categoryId, p1.price DESC
    LIMIT 5) AS u;

OR

WITH categoryIds AS (SELECT DISTINCT RAW p.categoryId
                     FROM products AS p
                     WHERE p.categoryId IS NOT NULL)
SELECT c AS categoryId,
       (SELECT p1.*
        FROM products AS p1
        WHERE p1.categoryId = c
        ORDER BY p1.categoryId, p1.price DESC
        LIMIT 5) AS top5
FROM categoryIds AS c ;
```

Comment: That looks very useful. I will look into it. Thank you for the quick reply.

Comment: _Window function is enterprise level feature_ :\ ... Unfortunately I am not able to use this.

Comment: Checkout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46856267/implement-rank-without-using-analytic-function

Comment: Thanks @vsr that almost perfect ... I posted a follow-up question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72461950/couchbase-n1ql-select-from-list-of-values-provided-by-parameter