# Couchbase/N1QL: SELECT FROM list of values provided by parameter

Tags: couchbase, sql++

As a follow-up to [Get top rows by "category" from a collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72447539/get-top-rows-by-category-from-a-collection) I still want to get the top5 products per categoryId, but I want to provide a pre-selected list of categoryIds that are relevant to me.

Starting with [vsr's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72447949/218472) from the original question, I could do something like:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT RAW p.categoryId
      FROM products AS p
      WHERE p.categoryId IN $categoryIds) AS c
UNNEST (SELECT p1.*
    FROM products AS p1
    WHERE p1.categoryId = c
    ORDER BY p1.categoryId, p1.price DESC
    LIMIT 5) AS u;
```

where the named parameter `$categoryIds` will be provided as an array `['cat1', 'cat2']`.

It feels a bit inefficient to do the `SELECT DISTINCT RAW p.categoryId FROM products AS p WHERE p.categoryId IN $categoryIds`, just to get something back that is essentially again my list of provided categoryIds.

I am sure there is more efficient way to express this. Something like:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM (VALUES IN $categoryIds) AS c
UNNEST ...;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE INDEX ix1 ON products(categoryId, price DESC);
```

So that below subquery in the Unnest uses index order and retrieves top 5 entries per category only irrespective of number of entries in specific category

If $categoryIds contain unique entries

```
SELECT u.*
FROM $categoryIds AS c
UNNEST (SELECT p1.*
       FROM products AS p1
       WHERE p1.categoryId = c
       ORDER BY p1.categoryId, p1.price DESC
       LIMIT 5) AS u;
```

For non-unique entries

```
SELECT u.*
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT RAW c1
      FROM $categoryIds AS c1 ) AS c
UNNEST (SELECT p1.*
    FROM products AS p1
    WHERE p1.categoryId = c
    ORDER BY p1.categoryId, p1.price DESC
    LIMIT 5) AS u;
```

Comment: What would be the downside of doing `FROM $categoryIds AS c` directly instead of `FROM (SELECT DISTINCT RAW c1 FROM $categoryIds AS c1 ) AS c`?

Comment: If everything unique in $categoryIds you can use it